# Jenkins Pipeline ssh steps sshPut all of a file type

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying move all of a particular file type to another server using SSH Steps. I'm specifically trying to use the sshPut to move over all .txt files. Here is the line I'm using:

```
sshPut remote: remote, from: "*.txt", into: "/the/destination/folder/"
```

and here is the error Jenkins is throwing:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /the/source/folder/*.txt does not exist.
```

I know that I have the sshsteps setup correctly. I've been able to push a single file and run some commands on the remote server. Can sshPut even handle a wildcard? I'm trying to avoid zipping everything up and doing the unzip on the remote server, if possible, but if that's what needs to happen, that's what needs to happen. I also have strict instructions to not use ssh keys, so scp is out of the question at the moment.

Update: based on susenj's advice I change my line to:

`sshPut remote: remote, from: "./", filterRegex: /\.txt$/, into: "/the/destination/folder/"`

and that worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex for sshPut works with the Groovy Syntax. Please refer to : https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin#sshput

What you can try is:
`sshPut remote: remote, from: "./", filterRegex: /.txt$/, into: "/the/destination/folder/"`

Comment: I had to use the FilterRegex argument, but this definitely put me on the right track. Here is the line that worked: `sshPut remote: remote, from: "./", filterRegex: /.txt$/, into: "/the/destination/folder/"`

Comment: Glad it worked. Edited my answer for future seekers.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same but somehow Jenkins is trying to copy the whole folder. 
This is my command: `sshPut remote: remote, from: './b2_gtk/', filterRegex: /\.ui$/, into: 'usr/gtk' `



but Jenkins gives me this error: `Failed SFTP MKDIR: root:usr/gtk/b2_gtk`

Comment: @SonggTùng you have to change transfer protocol.
Use that:  remote.fileTransfer = 'scp'

Comment: @SonggTùng did you manage to solve your issue? Faced it as well - copies whole folder